# Azure DevOps Server witadmin error 500 when downloading/uploading workitem XML

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-server-2020

We use On-premises XML process model (not inherited) on Azure DevOps Server 2020 Update 1.2.

Recently, on one of our collections, we cannot upload the xml description via witadmin. The exportwitd, importwitd, exportgloballist commands fail with error code 500: Internal Server Error.

In the Event Viewer there is an error in the Application log ArithmeticException: Overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation. The error occurs in the web service at /ourcollection/WorkItemTracking/v8.0/ClientService.asmx.

In the operation log (_oi), error 500 was recorded in the WorkItem Tracking application on the GetMetadata_Full command, command identifier GetMetadataEx2.

Reproduces with different projects in this collection.
There is no problem with other collections.

Find on SOF that the error ArithmeticException: Overflow or underflow in the arithmetic operation often occurs in ASP.Net MVC applications when uploading files larger than 1 Gb. And it is usually solved by disabling buffering. But it is not clear how a file with an xml description can be larger than 1 Gb (often wit file ~50 kb) and how to disable buffering, because this is done in the application source codes.

Comment: How about trying to restart the server machine of your Azure DevOps Server 2020?

Comment: We are planning a restart on March 31

Comment: After the restart, try the witadmin command again.